# Only in Remote Machine TestnG results are not generating ,It's resulting as Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

Tags: java, selenium, testng, extentreports

I know this is most common questions asked and got many solutions & have various probabilities for prone this issue. I had tried all the below possibilities but still no luck.

I know it would be bit lengthy, but wanted to give detail info based on previous experiences.

Firstly 2 Important things  to consider: (My Testsuite consists of more than 1K Test cases)

- This is working perfectly in local machines, same to same setup & code in remote throwing this issue
- If i run below 100 test cases its generating perfectly even in remote machines, but if its above than this then this is resulting as Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0 (So that extent reports are also not generating , **but all the test cases are executing perfectly**)

Possibilities Tried:

- Checked **@Test** annotations for all the methods
- Return type for all the @Test methods given **Void**
- Importing only **Testng Jars & packages** (Not Junit)
- all the methods have only **public access** (Not private)
- **TestNg** is properly configured in eclipse
- Swiped completely and installed all again(Done many restarts too :()
- All Required jars are properly **configured in the build path**

Configurations :

- Selenium - 3.7.1
- TestNG - 6.13
- Ant - 10.0.2
- Extent Report - 2.4.1
- Eclipse neon 4.6.3

Note : All the above configurations are same in local & remote expect OS local - win -7 & 10 , remote machine - 2012 server

I can understand without seeing the code, we cant analyse whats going wrong but i not sure it might help as it working in local machines however sharing the required code

Sample Test case :

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.UnexpectedException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

import com.pps.atm.pom.ccl.*;
import com.pps.atm.pom.core_framework_components.*;
import com.pps.atm.pom.dataproviders.*;
import com.pps.atm.pom.dataproviders.URL_Setup.settingUrls;
import com.pps.atm.pom.pages.admin.*;
import com.pps.atm.pom.pages.frontend.*;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

public class MyDev_Area_Local extends Local_DriverManager {

    @Test
    public void CK_DSK_LG_PopularToday_Newest_CTA_ActivateRewards_EUSignIn_SignInWithFB_Popup_Verification(
            Method method) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {

        ExtentTestManager.getTest().setDescription(
                "Menu Popular today -> Automation Specific Store Category-> Newest tab, activate rewards existing user sign in sign in with FB popup verification..");
        ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.INFO, "Test case : " + method.getName()
                + " - Execution Started With Thread ID  : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        System.out.println("Test case : " + method.getName() + " - Execution Started With Thread ID  : "
                + Thread.currentThread().getId());

        // Respective pages object creation
        objHomePage = new HomePage(objDriver);
        objMenuItems = new MenuItems(objDriver);
        objVIP = new Voucher_Intermediate_Page(objDriver);
        objComCTA = new Common_CTA_Buttons(objDriver);
        objSUPLinkPage = new SignIn_Joinfree_Popup(objDriver);
        objStoreCategoryPage = new StoreCategoryPage(objDriver)
```

Testng Xml File  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite
    name="PPS- Test Automation Framework for Desktop website - Local Execution"
    parallel="tests" thread-count="1">

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.pps.atm.pom.core_framework_components.TestListener" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="Execution on Firefox" parallel="methods" thread-count="1">

        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
        <parameter name="platform" value="WINDOWS" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.pps.atm.pom.devarea.MyDev_Area_Local" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Result :

```
   [testng] [Parent 4896, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
   [testng] Testcase : CK_DSK_WithoutReferal_SignUpBonus_As_Zero_And_ReferalBonusValue_As_Zero_UserReferralValue_AS_Zero_Setup_Verification_For_NewUserexecution completed with Thread ID : 10
   [testng] Testcase : CK_DSK_WithoutReferal_SignUpBonus_As_Zero_And_ReferalBonusValue_As_Zero_UserReferralValue_AS_Zero_Setup_Verification_For_NewUser - execution successfully completed :) ..!
   [testng] [GFX1-]: Receive IPC close with reason=AbnormalShutdown
   [testng] [GFX1-]: Receive IPC close with reason=AbnormalShutdown
   [testng] 1520507985755   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
   [testng] 1520507985799   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:19279
   [testng] 1520507986370   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\rust_mozprofile.pxDUcwVEb9zl"
   [testng] 1520507989413   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
   [testng] [Parent 3220, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
   [testng] 1520508003543   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 57333
   [testng] 1520508004282   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
   [testng] Mar 08, 2018 11:20:05 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
   [testng] INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
   [testng] Test execution started on browser  : firefox With Thread ID : 10
   [testng] Testcase : CK_DSK_WithoutReferal_SignUpBonus_As_Zero_And_ReferalBonusValue_As_Zero_UserReferralValue_AS_Zero_Setup_Verification_For_NewUser_From_JFPopUP - execution started ..!

       [testng] Test case : CK_DSK_WithoutReferal_SignUpBonus_As_Zero_And_ReferalBonusValue_As_Zero_UserReferralValue_AS_Zero_Setup_Verification_For_NewUser_From_JFPopUP - Execution Started With Thread ID  : 10
       [testng] JavaScript error: https://dev6ck.iamsavings.co.uk//themes/ck-storepage-v2/js/plugins.min.1519992761.js, line 22: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
       [testng] R Value as 1157784
       [testng] Count  tab 2
       [testng] SignIn bonus as : 0.0
       [testng] Referal bonus as : 0.0
       [testng] UserReferral_Bonus_Value as : 0.0
       [testng] Count  tab 2
       [testng] Testcase : CK_DSK_WithoutReferal_SignUpBonus_As_Zero_And_ReferalBonusValue_As_Zero_UserReferralValue_AS_Zero_Setup_Verification_For_NewUser_From_JFPopUP - execution Failed :( - please look into this ..!
       [testng] [Parent 3220, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
       [testng] [GFX1-]: Receive IPC close with reason=AbnormalShutdown
       [testng] [GFX1-]: Receive IPC close with reason=AbnormalShutdown
       [testng] [Child 1728, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 232: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 513
       [testng] We are on - onFinish method : Execution on Firefox and finishing the testsuite execution ..!
       [testng] ===============================================
       [testng] PPS- Test Automation Framework for Desktop website - Local Execution
       [testng] Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
       [testng] ===============================================
       [testng] The tests failed.
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL
    Total time: 286 minutes 2 seconds*
```

Test Case Sample  :

```
@Test
    public void CK_DSK_WithoutReferal_SignUpBonus_As_Zero_And_ReferalBonusValue_As_Zero_UserReferralValue_AS_Zero_Setup_Verification_For_NewUser_From_JFPopUP(
            Method method) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {

        ExtentTestManager.getTest().setDescription(
                "Navigating to Admins for Settings -> Parnter settings -> Setting Signup value as Zero & referal bonus value as Zero and verifying from the front end..");
        ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.INFO, "Test case : " + method.getName()
                + " - Execution Started With Thread ID  : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        System.out.println("Test case : " + method.getName() + " - Execution Started With Thread ID  : "
                + Thread.currentThread().getId());

        objSoftAssertion = new SoftAssert();
        objJF_PopUpPage = new JoinFreePage(objDriver);
        objHomePage = new HomePage(objDriver);
        objMyAccounts = new MyAccounts_Page(objDriver);
        objAdminCoreFunc = new Admin_Core_Functions(objDriver);
        objAdminLoginPage = new Admin_Login_Page(objDriver);
        objPartner_Settings = new Settings_Partner_Settings(objDriver);
        objSUPLinkPage = new SignIn_Joinfree_Popup(objDriver);
        objUsersPage = new Users_Users_Page(objDriver);
        objReferEarnPage = new Refer_Earn_Page(objDriver);
        objAdmin_Search_Page = new Admin_Search_Page(objDriver);

        objComCon = new Common_Controls(objDriver);
        objComCTA = new Common_CTA_Buttons(objDriver);

        ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.INFO, "Navigating to home page and Joining In ...");
        objHomePage.navigateURL(objDriver);

        objHomePage.signinPopup_Header_LinkClick(objDriver);
        objSUPLinkPage.linkSignUp_Click(objDriver);

        ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.INFO, "Navigating to get captcha page and returns captcha code...");
        String strCaptchaValue = objSUPLinkPage.joinFreePopUp_Captch_Generation(objDriver);

        ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.INFO,
                "Return back to Join free page and entering all join free page field values ...");
        String strNewJoin_UserEmail_1 = objJF_PopUpPage.joinFreePage_FeildValues_Entering_forUserName(objDriver,
                strCaptchaValue);
        String strNewJoin_Password_1 = testdata.get(1).get("strPassword").trim();
        String strNewJoin_UserName_1 = testdata.get(1).get("strFirstName").trim();
        objHomePage.userLoggedIn_Verification(objDriver);

        ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.INFO, "Navigating to ReferFriend & fetching referral link ...");
        objHomePage.dropdown_MYAccounts_Click(objDriver);
        objMyAccounts.topMenu_ReferFriend_Navigation(objDriver);
        String strNewJoin_Referal_Link = objReferEarnPage.fetch_Referal_Link(objDriver);
        String[] strSplitValue = strNewJoin_Referal_Link.split("/r=");
        String strNewJoin_Referal_Value = strSplitValue[1];

        System.out.println("R Value as " + strNewJoin_Referal_Value);

        objSUPLinkPage.logOut_Verification(objDriver);

        ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.INFO,
                "Navigating to admin URls and navigating to admin home page...");
        String strFurtherStatus_0 = CCL_Class.General.tabToggle_NavigateNewURL_Tab_count_2(objDriver,
                (URL_Setup.settingUrls.admin_Url_Base).trim());
        objAdminLoginPage.enter_Credentials_And_Homepage_Navigation(objDriver);

        // Setting User Referal Bonus values in user sub tab @ User main tab
        ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.INFO,
                "Navigating to adminSettings -> user main tab -> User sub tab -> User referral bonus ..");
        objAdminLoginPage.mainmenu_Users_Click(objDriver);
        objUsersPage.subMenu_Users_Navigation(objDriver);

        // Admin Search page
        objAdmin_Search_Page.searchPage_select_SearchBy(objDriver, "User Email");
        objAdmin_Search_Page.searchPage_Input_Keyword_UserTab(objDriver, strNewJoin_UserEmail_1);
        objAdmin_Search_Page.button_Submit_Users_Tab_User(objDriver);

        objUsersPage.editButton_ResultTable(objDriver, strNewJoin_Referal_Value);

        ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.INFO,
                "Setting user referal bonus values in user edit page & saving the values  ...");
        float intUserReferral_Bonus_Value = (float) objUsersPage
                .editPartnerDetails_input_User_Referral_Bonus_Value(objDriver, 0);
        objUsersPage.button_Save_Click(objDriver);

        ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.INFO,
                "Navigating to adminSettings -> Parnter settings -> Setting Signup bonus values..");
        objAdminLoginPage.mainmenu_Settings_Click(objDriver);
        objPartner_Settings.subMenu_Partner_Settings_Navigation(objDriver);
        objPartner_Settings.editPartnerDetails_Editbutton_Click(objDriver);

        ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.INFO,
                "Setting Signup & referal bonus values in Parnter settings edit page & saving the values  ...");
        float intSignUp_Bonus_Value = (float) objPartner_Settings.editPartnerDetails_input_SignUp_Bonus_Value(objDriver,
                0);
        float intReferal_Bonus_Value = (float) objPartner_Settings
                .editPartnerDetails_input_Referal_Bonus_Value(objDriver, 0);
        objPartner_Settings.button_Save_Click(objDriver);

        // will be removed
        System.out.println("SignIn bonus as : " + intSignUp_Bonus_Value);
        System.out.println("Referal bonus as : " + intReferal_Bonus_Value);
        System.out.println("UserReferral_Bonus_Value as : " + intUserReferral_Bonus_Value);

        ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.INFO, "Opening new tab and navigating to join free page to join...");
        String strFurtherStatus = CCL_Class.General.tabToggle_NavigateNewURL_Tab_count_2(objDriver,
                (URL_Setup.settingUrls.url_Home).trim());
        objHomePage.signinPopup_Header_LinkClick(objDriver);
        objSUPLinkPage.linkSignUp_Click(objDriver);

        if (strFurtherStatus.contains("Success")) {

            objJF_PopUpPage.joinFreePage_Navigated_Verification(objDriver);

            ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.INFO,
                    "Opened new tab & Navigating to navigate join free page ...");
            String strCaptchaValue_1 = objSUPLinkPage.joinFreePage_Captch_Generation_Tab_Count_3(objDriver);

            ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.INFO,
                    "Return back to Join free page and entering all join free page field values ...");
            objJF_PopUpPage.joinFreePage_FeildValues_Entering(objDriver, strCaptchaValue_1);
            objHomePage.userLoggedIn_Verification(objDriver);

            objHomePage.dropdown_MYAccounts_Click(objDriver);
            objMyAccounts.topMenu_MyEarnings_Navigation(objDriver);
            objMyAccounts.tab_MyEarnings_CBEarnings_Navigation(objDriver);

            float intAvailableCB = objMyAccounts.cash_MyEarningsTab_AvailableCB(objDriver);

            // Asserting the Cashback value with backend singup bonus data
            if (intAvailableCB == intSignUp_Bonus_Value) {

                ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.INFO,
                        "Successfully, Asserted live cashback & backend singup bonus data");

            } else {

                ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.FAIL,
                        "Assertion failed - for live cashback & backend singup bonus data");
            }

            System.out.println("SignIn bonus from frontend as : " + intAvailableCB);

        } else {

            ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.FAIL,
                    "not able to Open new tab and navigating to join free page to join...");
        }

        ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.INFO,
                "Verified successfully that user as Joined with respective signup  values entered in backend ...");
        ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.INFO, "Testcase : " + method.getName()
                + "execution completed with Thread ID : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        System.out.println("Testcase : " + method.getName() + "execution completed with Thread ID : "
                + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on the screen shots , edited the post @ DebanjanB

Comment: Can you update the question with the _remote execution_ setup and the complete error stack trace?

Comment: Updated the result in the post - Nothing specific errors - just its coming as all the 0. Remote setup details are same as defined in Configurations in post only difference in OS in remote as windows server 2012

Comment: See `Testcase : CK_DSK_WithoutReferal_SignUpBonus_As_Zero_And_ReferalBonusValue_As_Zero_UserReferralValue_AS_Zero_Setup_Verification_For_NewUser_From_JFPopUP`. Share the relevant _code_ and _HTML_

Comment: Shared testcase but HTML is bit tricky because execution  goes for multiple applications and executes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166461/discussion-between-kris-and-debanjanb).

Answer (score 0):

Rename your test class and concatenate with "Test" as suffix or prefix.Conventionally , build automation tools like ANT or MAVEN recognise test classes through this suffix or prefix. Your class name should be like :

```
MyDev_Area_LocalTest
```

Comment: Even after prefixing as above and executing also it had resulted the same as zero. @ ManMohan